# jquery click on live generated element on modal window does not work

Tags: jquery

I have a modal window which opens up a login form, then i click on a button and its code is:

```
$("#delete_button").click(function(){
    $(this).before('<a href="#" id="delete_this">delete</a>');
});
```

then i add the following code to check if when i click the delete_this anchor will work

```
$("#delete_this").click(function(){
    console.log('1');
    return false;
});
```

but it doesnt work.

i even tried with live and still nothing.

im thinking it might be the modal window that causes it or somehow it cant find what i click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the code inside the click function

```
$("#delete_button").click(function(){
    $(this).before('<a href="#" id="delete_this">delete</a>');
    $("#delete_this").click(function(){
      console.log('1');
      return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: No worries! Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$('#delete_this').live('click', function() { /*...*/ });
```

to address dynamicly inserted nodes.